# concat two data frames using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sum, dataframe

I have two pandas data frames, the first one has the following structure  :

```
df1 : 

 id | age | sexe | language | country |
----|-----|------|----------|---------|
 1  | 35  | M    | FR       | FR      |
 2  | 20  | F    | EN       | EN      |
 3  | 60  | M    | IT       | IT      |
```

The second one has the following structure :

```
df2 : 

 id | act| secs  | 
----|----|-------|
 1  | A  | 5     | 
 1  | B  | 10    | 
 1  | C  | 35    | 
 2  | A  | 1     | 
 2  | B  | 10    | 
 2  | C  | 100   | 
 2  | D  | 50    |
 3  | A  | 20    |
 3  | B  | 25    |
 3  | D  | 10    |
```

I want to sum `secs` for each user using the `id`, I want to get this data frame:

```
 id | age | sexe | language | country |secs |
----|-----|------|----------|---------|-----|     
 1  | 35  | M    | FR       | FR      | 50  |
 2  | 20  | F    | EN       | EN      | 161 |
 3  | 60  | M    | IT       | IT      | 55  |
```

Comment: If any of the answer provided solves your question please accept it to close the questions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you could use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) for your `df2` with `sum` for you 'secs' column and then [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) that dataframe with your original:

```
df3 = df2.groupby('id')['secs'].sum()
df4 = pd.concat([df1.set_index('id'), df3], axis=1).reset_index()


In [120]: df4
Out[120]:
   id  age sexe language country  secs
0   1   35    M       FR      FR    50
1   2   20    F       EN      EN   161
2   3   60    M       IT      IT    55
```

In one line:

```
pd.concat([df1.set_index('id'), df2.groupby('id')['secs'].sum()], axis=1).reset_index()
```

**Timing**:

```
In [122]: %timeit pd.concat([df1.set_index('id'), df2.groupby('id')['secs'].sum()], axis=1).reset_index()
100 loops, best of 3: 2.73 ms per loop

In [123]: %timeit pd.merge(df1, df2.groupby('id')['secs'].sum().reset_index(), on=['id'])
100 loops, best of 3: 3.44 ms per loop

In [124]: %timeit pd.merge(df1, df2.groupby('id', as_index=False)['secs'].sum(), on=['id'])
100 loops, best of 3: 3.73 ms per loop

In [125]: %timeit df1.set_index('id').join(df2.groupby('id')['secs'].sum()).reset_index()
100 loops, best of 3: 2.88 ms per loop
```

Comment: Can you add test with `join` solution?

Comment: @jezrael added. Almost the same speed as with `pd.concat` but not quite :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) `df1` with  [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) and [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) on `df2`:

```
print df2.groupby('id')['secs'].sum().reset_index()
   id  secs
0   1    50
1   2   161
2   3    55

print pd.merge(df1, df2.groupby('id')['secs'].sum().reset_index(), on=['id'])
   id  age sexe language country  secs
0   1   35    M       FR      FR    50
1   2   20    F       EN      EN   161
2   3   60    M       IT      IT    55
```

Or use parameter `as_index=False` in [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
print pd.merge(df1, df2.groupby('id', as_index=False)['secs'].sum(), on=['id'])
   id  age sexe language country  secs
0   1   35    M       FR      FR    50
1   2   20    F       EN      EN   161
2   3   60    M       IT      IT    55
```

Or you can use [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
print df1.set_index('id').join(df2.groupby('id')['secs'].sum()).reset_index()
   id  age sexe language country  secs
0   1   35    M       FR      FR    50
1   2   20    F       EN      EN   161
2   3   60    M       IT      IT    55
```