# Use content of 2 lists and combine (stringified) values on same index into a third list

Tags: python

Which method should i use to concate two dataframes in Pandas like:

```
before: dataframes1 =[1,2,3,4,5,6] dataframes2 =['a','b','c','d','e','f']
after: ['1a','2b','3c','4d','5e','6f']
```

Comment: Those are lists. What does this have to do with Pandas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [concat two data frames using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35795496/concat-two-data-frames-using-pandas)

Comment: @HeyHoo That's not even related to what OP wants to do, which is join strings.

Comment: Oh ok, my bad. The title's were similiar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop to traverse both lists and concatenate the results in a new list:

```
dataframes1 =[1,2,3,4,5,6] 
dataframes2 =['a','b','c','d','e','f']

result = []
for i in range(len(dataframes1)):
    result.append(str(dataframes1[i])+dataframes2[i])
print(result)
```

**-** Also you can simplify the syntax of the loop by invoking it in the list initialization:

```
dataframes1 =[1,2,3,4,5,6] 
dataframes2 =['a','b','c','d','e','f']

result = [str(dataframes1[i])+dataframes2[i] for i in range(len(dataframes1))]
print(result)
```

**-** Or use the `zip()` function to make the syntax clearer, as @patrick-artner suggested:

```
dataframes1 =[1,2,3,4,5,6] 
dataframes2 =['a','b','c','d','e','f']

result = [str(a)+b for a,b in zip(dataframes1, dataframes2)]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
['1a', '2b', '3c', '4d', '5e', '6f']
```

Comment: @patrick-artner I added your suggestion to the answer, thanks.

Comment: Wow, these are a very good solutions. Why is this Topic closed?? please reopen

Comment: I found an easier Way: 
complaints = dataset["title"].values+' :: '+dataset["desc"].values

Comment: @dazzafact It's closed because there is a very similar question about it

Comment: no, i dont want just to merge arrays, i asked to cancate strings in array

Comment: @dazzafact Also, you should have included more info about your dataframes in the question.

Comment: the two examples of me are very clear!

Comment: ok, i see, they now have changed the topics 

Answer (score -1):

**If it is pandas dataframe and both columns are strings, you can concatenate them;**

```
import pandas as pd
# create empty dataframe
dataframes3 = pd.DataFrame()

# Concatenation of two columns 
dataframes3["result"] = dataframes1["column1"] + dataframes2["column1"]
```

**If it is Python List.**

```
result = map(lambda (s1,s2): s1+s2, zip(dataframes1, dataframes2))
```